# Why is Teams not accessible to me?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

If I visit https://stackoverflow.com/teams/create/free I see the following:

> [image: this product is not accessible]

> Sorry, this product is not accessible to you.

Why is Teams is not accessible to me? Is it because I already set up one free team? I see the same message while logged off (in browser's private mode).

Comment: @Rob I would say that comment you linked to is outdated: [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362203/369802) was posted on MSE after that. As far as I know, that's not 'expired' since it's supposed to be 'forever'.

Comment: I think the point Rob is making here, @Tinkeringbell , is that they suspect the OP already had a free teams set up, and that when they try to create another they are denied; not that their existing one has expired.

Comment: @Larnu That would be my guess too. I don't see anything in the comment Rob linked confirming that interpretation though. The linked comment is a reply to someone asking if there's still any possibility to get the 'old' free promotion after it expired... All that comment seems to say is 'No, the offer is expired and can't be added to *any* account anymore'. There's no mention of the fact that it's impossible to get a second free team on an existing account. The entire conversation there is about something else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error is displayed when your country is detected as being one on an embargo list that we must follow. It unfortunately means we cannot engage in new business with you while the embargo remains in effect, and includes our Free plan.

Comment: And which embargo list will that be?

Comment: At least any ones that the United States are bound to. But I am not familiar with every embargo our legal team says must be followed, only that there is a list that our legal team says we cannot do business with.

Comment: That is a bit strange, because I've been able to reproduce on my end (I think αλεχολυτ and I even live in the same city), and last time I checked, unless SO shifted to military finance and/or training, Russian citizens should not be affected by the embargo list - are you saying that any and all paid products of SO are now inaccessible for any user from Russia?

Comment: If that is a country on the list, yes. It is not a list I even have access to view - it is restricted only to the legal team and those who make changes for them. So I couldn't even tell you what all countries are on it. I can only tell you the list is the source of this error.

Comment: So... I suppose we need a response from the legal team then? It is a pretty major consequence for Russian-based users (or users from any other potentially embargoed country) which calls for an official list of countries that cannot use any of the paid products of SO. And I highly doubt this list cannot be shared

Comment: It is highly unlikely that our legal team would come respond to this, as they do not engage in discussions about their decisions. The most that would happen is that they decide we can share a list of all countries, but it doesn't sound like that would really change anything for you, since it's already clear via the message that your country is on the list...

Comment: That's... a bit of an unfortunate policy of the legal team on a community-driven network, don't you think? Yes, a disclosure of the full list that is clearly not a state secret would definitely help clear things up and create a reference for us to point the unfortunate users from said countries to even if it does not change the status-quo per se.

Comment: Why not _"Sorry, this product is not available in your country."_ then? At least to avoid confusion and speculation about the reason.

Comment: @41686d6564 I think that would be a much better error message. I can speak from experience trying to support error messages (or just browsing Meta requests about vague errors) that we are definitely not the best at writing them and there are many I would love to see changed.

Comment: @animuson to clarify - this list is not a business decision but a legal one? So you can't legally provide the service even if you wanted to, is that correct?

Comment: Speaking of, we are still waiting for the list and haven't forgotten about it :) Any chance of getting it earlier than 6 to 8?

Comment: Doesn't make sense at all as teams could be distributed all over the world in 2022.