# Why is Stack Overflow for Teams not accessible to me?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

I'm tried to create a team for my colleagues and students, but I get a message like "*Sorry, this product is not accessible to you*".
I know that a similar question [was asked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411096/why-is-teams-not-accessible-to-me) and the answer was

> This error is displayed when your country is detected as being one on an embargo list that we must follow. It unfortunately means we cannot engage in new business with you while the embargo remains in effect, and includes our Free plan.

That's very strange, because the country in my profile is Ukraine. **How can Ukraine, which is now on the edge of fighting for democracy in Europe, be in the embargo list?**  So this answer is not an answer.

Of course, Ukraine not in the [embargo list](https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/embargoed-countries). As fo IP address, whatismyip.com show me Ukraine (actually central Ukraine).

I has and using paid subscriptions from Google, Microsoft, GitHub and other US companies, but can't use a free offer from Stack Overflow?! That's nonsense...

Is this a bug or a joke?

Comment: These embargo lists are not something SE has _any_ control over, yet being a US company, they're bound by them. You could do with being a little less offended at SE.

Comment: Seems weird for one free product to not allow access but the other free product does

Comment: @KevinB I'm guessing that legally, the free version of teams is considered a trial of a paid product, and thus requires the same access restrictions?

Comment: Eh, it does look like a bug given that it is highly unlikely Ukraine is on any of the embargo lists of the US. Are you sure your IP address geolocation does not fall under one of the embargo'd countries?

Comment: Oleg has a point… What country does https://www.whatismyip.com show you?

Comment: @Cerbrus I don't know about the current free tier, but I'm on the [free promotional "Basic" tier](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406574/2821954), and as the creator, it asked for my credit card when creating the Team, even if it's never charged.

Comment: I didn't have to provide one when I created a free team earlier in the year, @AndrewT. ; I wouldn't have created it if I were asked.

Comment: Just to confirm, the free tier is indeed under the same restrictions as the paid tiers, as confirmed in [this answer by staff on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/377404). I have no idea how Stack maintains these blocks, be it by IP ranges or otherwise, but I think the most likely explanation here is that your location is coming through to the site as something _other_ than Ukraine. Your country of residence won't be determined by your profile in these cases, it will be determined by some other mechanism.